# Digraph minimal sub-graph algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, directed-graph

which algorithm can find directed sub-graph (сomposed of same vertices & minimal amount of edges), and all paths will remain ?

G(V,E) --> find minimal G'(V,E') where V=V & E' in E, and all paths remain.

thanks.

Comment: By "all paths remain", do you mean "every two vertices, which were connected before by some path, are still connected in the modified graph", ie. the paths (as sequences of vertices) do not remain paths? That is a np-complete problem (Hamiltonian cycle is trivially convertible to it).

Comment: and "E' in E" should be subset, shouldn't it?

Comment: yes you're right, but what is the best algorithm to do so ? 
if i run on edges, and for each edge (v, u) try to find with BFS (without the edge itself other path from v to u, if found one delete this edge) ? is there a better way ?